# Является ли вводным оборот "тем более"?

Tags: пунктуация

Писал в однм сообществе такое предложение: "Похоже, тут юмора, а тем более(,) стеба(,) тут все равно никто не понимает". И, честно говоря, не пойму: надо выделять запятаыми оборот "тем более" или нет?

Answer (score 2):

"... юмора, а тем более стёба, тут всё равно...". Я думаю, что фразу в запятых можно безболезненно (без изменения смысла) удалить, а коли так - запятые нужны. Я согласен с [@Инна](/users/466/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0) не потому что вчера был Женский день, а потому, что она, по-моему, права.

Answer (score 1):

"...а тем более стеба" - это уточнение, оно-то и обособляется.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что "тем более" начинает собой присоединительный оборот, поэтому в любом случае здесь запятая не нужна